# What is the correct way to migrate a SharePoint web app from classic to claims based authentication?

Tags: powershell, authentication, claims-based-auth, classic-mode-auth

In my new project, the client wants us to convert several web applications from Classic to Claims. I've read many articles on the steps to convert a SharePoint web application from classic mode to claims mode. This [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article lists the steps, the gist of which is:

```
$WebAppName = "http://yourWebAppUrl"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$wa.UseClaimsAuthentication = $true
$wa.Update()
```

But, I also came across another set of steps [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/03/25/change-sharepoint-authentication-from-classic-mode-to-claims-based.aspx), the gist of which is:

```
$WebAppName = “http://win-hgdsnnuakhv”
$account = "WIN-HGDSNNUAKHV\Administrator"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
Set-SPwebApplication $wa –AuthenticationProvider (New-SPAuthenticationProvider) –Zone Default
```

This has been bugging me but which set of steps is the right way to do the migration? And, the MSDN link says that you can't revert to Classic once you've migrated to Claims but I verified that you actually can by setting `UseClaimsAuthentication = $true` to `$false`. Why would they list something like that if that can actually be done? Can someone please explain to me if I'm seeing it all in the right way or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Migration of SP2010 web app from Classic to Claims:

1) It is irreversible process as mention in [Microsoft](http://sharepointegg.blogspot.in/2011/01/reverting-claim-based-authentication-to.html) site. But its not correct.
   You need to do some extra work to revert back.Check it out here [Sharepoint egg](http://sharepointegg.blogspot.in/2011/01/reverting-claim-based-authentication-to.html)

2) There is no support for conversation from SP UI, you can do it either powershell or programmatically.

3) There are few steps for converting from Classic to Claims

```
$WebAppName = "http://yourWebAppUrl"
$account = "yourDomain\yourUser"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName

Set-SPwebApplication $wa -AuthenticationProvider (New-SPAuthenticationProvider) -Zone Default
#This causes a prompt about migration. Click Yes and continue.

#The following step sets the user as an administrator for the site. 
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$account = (New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $account -identitytype 1).ToEncodedString()

#After the user is added as an administrator, we set the policy so that the user can have the correct access.
$zp = $wa.ZonePolicies("Default")
$p = $zp.Add($account,"PSPolicy")
$fc=$wa.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole("FullControl")
$p.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($fc)
$wa.Update()

#The final step is to trigger the user-migration process.
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$wa.MigrateUsers($true)
```

For more refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953202(v=office.14).aspx